# How I set the 'top' css value as a variable using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

How I set the 'top' css value as a variable using $(this) ?

Thus far I have not been able to do so with this code:

```
    $("#thumb").click(function () {

        var TopV = $(this).css('top');
        alert(TopV)
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

That code snippet is attempting to read the CSS 'top' property, not write to it.  It probably does not exist on most elements.

Did you mean that you wanted to set it to some value, like this?

```
$(this).css('top', '5px');
```

[More info on the css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

You should also be aware that the 'top' property is only meaningful if the element it is set on doesn't have 'static' positioning - that is, if it has absolute, relative or fixed.  Otherwise it's ignored: it won't do anything, and probably won't be readable.

[More info on the top CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to set it to?  Something like this will do it:

```
   $("#thumb").click(function () {
        var targetTop = '100px';
        $(this).css('top', targetTop);
        var TopV = $(this).css('top');
        alert(TopV)
    });
```

Comment: This won't do it. .css('top', [value]) doesn't allow integer values, and you must specify a unit (px or em or whatever)

Comment: @reinder, it does take a number — try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
$(this).html( "top: " + offset.top );
```

you can try [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) also